# JSP Code "Reuse"

Tags: jsp, richfaces, code-reuse

I have a few jsp files with different content but with the same sidebar.

How can I reuse the sidebar code?
The sidebar is currently a `rich:panelMenu`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sidebar in an extra jsp file and include it with facelets . Here is a nice article about facelets and jsf: [Facelets fits JSF like a glove](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/).

You can also use subviews:

```
<f:subview id="sidebar">
  <jsp:include page="sidebar.jsp" />
</f:subview>
```

Comment: The `f:subview` tag belongs in the include page, not in the master page. Otherwise you may risk duplicate component id errors.

Comment: I think that does not matter, you can put it inside or outside: http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/subview.shtml

Comment: When you put it outside, you **risk** duplicate component ID errors. It may work, but it may also not work. When you put it inside, it will *always* work without any risk on troubles. Further, do you realize that you're citing from one of the worst Java EE sources?

Comment: Yes I know its not a good source, but in many other samples you will find it this way round too. You might be right about the risk though.